# Telerik "classic controls" for ASP.NET

Tags: .net, asp.net, telerik

I've got a project that uses Telerik controls, but they not like Telerik stuff I've had experience with. It looks like I have a separate assembly for each component, like RadAjax.Net2.dll, RadGrid.Net2.dll and so on. I don't really understand what all this is about because the only way of having Telerik controls organized that I'm aware of is a single assembly Telerik.Web.UI.

Could anyone please explain me what version it is when I have a single assembly for every component? What term should I use when I'm referring to this stuff? Does "classic controls" sound right? I can't download anything like it from Telerik website for my experiments, what can I do? Any useful information is really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Telerik controls always used to come in separate assemblies, I wouldn't like to speculate on the version you've got though as it's been a while since I used them.  Do you have a particular problem or are you just after a way to describe them?

Comment: The version you have was last updated more than two years ago, but you should be able to see some demos at http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-classic 

Comment: Well, I'm trying to solve the problem described here http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=2234567 . It looks like RadAjax component from the old assembly used by my application may be the cause of this. So, here I am trying to find out more about this stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[RadControls for ASP.NET Ajax](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax.aspx) come in a single-assembly fashion - Telerik.Web.UI.dll. You are using RadControls "Classic" which is the older version. RadControls "Classic" are no longer updated and you cannot download them from the Telerik web site.